# kubernetes pod container keep on restarting with CrashLoopBackoff

Tags: kubernetes

I am working with minikube , currently creating config-maps attaching as volume to the pod
this is my test-config.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2016-02-18T18:52:05Z
  name: bb-configmap
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "516"
  uid: b4952dc3-d670-11e5-8cd0-68f728db1985
data:
  game.properties: |
    enemies=aliens
    enemies.cheat=true
    lives=3
    enemies.cheat.level=noGoodRotten
    secret.code.passphrase=UUDDLRLRBABAS
    secret.code.allowed=true
    secret.code.lives=30
  ui.properties: |
    color.good=purple
    color.bad=yellow
    allow.textmode=true
    how.nice.to.look=fairlyNice
```

my pod.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: busybox-container
      image: busybox
      volumeMounts:
        - name: config-dir
          mountPath: /etc/config
  volumes:
    - name: config-dir
      configMap:
        name: bb-configmap
```

when I start my pod it is keep on restarting saying crashloopbackoff.
As per my understanding it should be in completed state ,but it is in crashLoopBackOff
please find the describe pod details below

```
Containers:
  busybox-container:
    Container ID:   docker://bb650f7fe715855adb8ca8ab3be04e62924bcda2abfccff78e5e30cf20e2dc02
    Image:          busybox
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://busybox@sha256:4f47c01fa91355af2865ac10fef5bf6ec9c7f42ad2321377c21e844427972977
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Fri, 21 Aug 2020 17:23:20 +0530
      Finished:     Fri, 21 Aug 2020 17:23:20 +0530
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  11
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /etc/config from config-dir (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-zkt9s (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  config-dir:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      bb-configmap
    Optional:  false
  default-token-zkt9s:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-zkt9s
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                  From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                 ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  <unknown>            default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/mypod to minikube
  Normal   Pulling    35m (x4 over 36m)    kubelet, minikube  Pulling image "busybox"
  Normal   Pulled     34m (x4 over 36m)    kubelet, minikube  Successfully pulled image "busybox"
  Normal   Created    34m (x4 over 36m)    kubelet, minikube  Created container busybox-container
  Normal   Started    34m (x4 over 36m)    kubelet, minikube  Started container busybox-container
  Warning  BackOff    74s (x157 over 35m)  kubelet, minikube  Back-off restarting failed container
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the PodSpec, `restartPolicy` [defaults to `Always`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#podspec-v1-core). For the Pod to go to `Completed` instead of `CrashLoopBackOff`, this field should be set to `OnFailure`.

The default behaviour is that Kubernetes expects a Pod to always be running, unless otherwise specified.

Comment: how to identify the failure reason

Comment: when I change  restart policy to never ,it is in completed state.
Actually it should be in running state right ? when we starting a pod

Comment: It'll be in Running state only until your application exits. If you don't check soon enough, that makes sense. Your Pod isn't doing anything, it quits straight away.

Comment: Any linux pod behave the same way ? Or only busybox image ?